# Problem with independent random variables $X,Y$ with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem**

In order to keep a room illuminated without interruption there are two light bulbs, when one burns out, it is replaced by the other. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the useful life times of each light bulb (in $10^3$ hours) and suppose that these times are independent and have an exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda=1$.

1) Find the joint density of $(X,Y)$

2) Calculate the probability that the room keeps illuminated at least $2000$ hours.

Attempt at a solution:

1) Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$$$=e^{-x}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)e^{-y}I_{(0,\infty)}(y)$$

2) This probability is the probability $P(X+Y \geq 2)$

I've tried doing $$P(X+Y\geq 2)=\int_{2}^{+\infty}\int_{2-x}^{+\infty}e^{-x}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)e^{-y}I_{(0,\infty)}(y)dydx$$

This is clearly wrong since for $x=3$, $f_Y(y)=f_Y(-1)=0$. I am having some difficulty trying to properly define the region of integration. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $X$ can be as small as $0$, so you're definitely not capturing the full area. Perhaps consider the conditions on $y$ if $0<x<2$ and $x>2$ separately.

Comment: Or, to be a bit fancier - you could use the transformation $u=x+y, v=-x+y$ under which the region becomes $u\ge 2, -u \le v \le u$.

Comment: Yet another possible approach: $P(X + Y \ge 2) = 1 - P(X + Y < 2)$ and the integral for $P(X + Y < 2)$ is probably a bit simpler to set up.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the suggestion, I could describe this region easily.